Is my avocado dying or is this transplant shock?
Years ago we started this avocado from a pit in a pot, and the root grew through the hole of the pot. When I was pulling the avocado I nicked a pretty large root. However, the root system was still intact. The leafs all look like this.

Hello, and welcome to the site.  To ask the obvious, is it getting enough water?
